# multiple stacked area charts nvd3 - errors

Tags: charts, nvd3.js, stacked

I am trying to create a dashboard with multiple area charts on the same page. I have two issues.

1. I want to get rid of the small circle on the chart that indicates value point and moves along with the cursor and the interactiveguideline. What is the name of that circle and how do I remove it?
2. After some research, I figured out how to change the Y-axis values to percentages. But I would like some graphs to show percentages and others to show regular numbers. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Include some code. It's much easier for people to give you useful answers when they can see what you've actually tried.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I think I am okay for now (but I will probably have more questions soon).

Comment: Can you close/post the answer to the question. Thank you.